# xpages ext library mobile application calendar issue

Tags: xpages-extlib

I m developing xpages Mobil app with Ext library on domino 8.5.3. The problem I faced is the calendar is not working properly. It is displayed white screen.

Please help.

Comment: Please show your code (XPage's source code).

Comment: <xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="Main">
  <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="Main">
   <xp:inputText id="date1">
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper2"
     dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox">
    </xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
     <xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short">
     </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
   </xp:inputText>
  </xe:appPage>
 </xe:singlePageApp>
</xp:view>